# What is the order of events binded by Views in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

```
var ViewA = Backbone.View.extend({
        events: { 'click a': 'do_something' },
        do_something: function() { console.log('ViewA::do_something()'); }
});

var ViewB = Backbone.View.extend({
        events: { 'click a.some_class': 'do_something' },
        do_something: function() { console.log('ViewB::do_something()'); }
});

////////

<a class="some_class">Click me</a>
```

I've got 2 views setup that binds to click events as shown above. For some reason, ViewA's handler always gets called first.

I've tried:

- Changing the order that the JS is loaded.
- Changing the order that the views are initialized.

This leads me to believe that is is down to the specificity of the selectors, but that doesn't make sense either given that the selector in ViewB is *more* specific than the one in ViewA - why would the more general selector get called first?

Comment: It might have something to do with the `cid` properties of your views. Perhaps there is some sorting function performed on the values and that is the ordering you are seeing...

Comment: Why would you have 2 different Views listen to events on the same element? The whole point of a View is to have specific logic for a DOM subtree in one class so that responsibilities are clearly defined.

Comment: @TheShellfishMeme - it is not too far fetched to have more than one view react to a certain action.

Comment: @Lix Nested views listening to the same DOM events sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @TheShellfishMeme - perhaps I missed something... How do you see these views as nested?

Comment: @Lix if they weren't inside each other (ViewA's `el` being a parent of  ViewB's `el` or vice versa), the same events would not trigger twice on both of them, since events are delegated on just the `el`. So they have to be inside each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I figured this out - for anyone that runs into this in the future. The ordering of the events are determined by (in order of importance):

1. The specificity of the "el" element of the view
2. The specificity of the event selector
3. The order the views are initialized